# PlatformNotSupportedException in DbContext through COM

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, com, vb6

I wrote a simple .net framework library that exposed itself to COM in the appropriate way and I could then create and use the library from VB6. This library did some calculation and read databases rows through Entity Framework.

I have written a .net 7 (Core) version of this library, which still uses EF (not EF Core) and when the library is used through a .net console app, does the same job as the original (i.e. the code is fundamentally working).

I have exposed this to COM by:

a. Adding the following to the .csproj

```
<EnableComHosting>true</EnableComHosting>
<PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
```

b. Registering the resulting comhost dll

```
regsvr32 my-library.comhost.dll
```

c. Creating an instance of the object in VB6

```
Set obj = CreateObject("new:{C3BBD3C1-FED4-43B0-A9CE-38C356D2BA8E}")
```

The object is successfully created and when I call one of the exposed functions in the object the code starts executing within the .net library (I can attach and step through using Visual Studio) but when it gets to the point where the `DbContext` is being created, I get the following:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception.'
ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize
PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.
```

I understand it is trying to say that in the current environment it is executing, it doesn't know what the target platform is supposed to be? I'm not sure what I should/could do about this to allow this issue to be resolved.

Edit 1:

Full exception details:

```
System.TypeInitializationException
  HResult=0x80131534
  Message=The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception.
  Source=EntityFramework
  StackTrace:
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig.get_DefaultInstance()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection..ctor(DbContext context, String nameOrConnectionString)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext..ctor()
   at LibTest.Domain.Infrastructure.ConfigurationDbContext..ctor() in X:\SOURCE\WEBSERVE\1\LibTestCore\LibTestCore.Domain\Infrastructure\ConfigurationDbContext.cs:line 27
   at LibTest.Domain.Configuration.Concrete.DbConfigurationRepository..ctor() in X:\SOURCE\WEBSERVE\1\LibTestCore\LibTestCore.Domain\Concrete\Configuration\DbConfigurationRepository.cs:line 12
   at LibTest.Domain.Concrete.Configuration.LegacyConfigurationRepository..ctor()
   at LibTest.Domain.Concrete.Legacy.ComInterface..ctor() in X:\SOURCE\WEBSERVE\1\LibTestCore\LibTestCore.Domain\Concrete\Legacy\ComInterface.cs:line 16
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean wrapExceptions)

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.ClientConfigPaths(string, bool)
    System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetPaths(string, bool)
    System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.ConfigPaths.get()
    System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.GetStreamName(string)
    System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.IsAppConfigHttp.get()
    System.Configuration.Internal.DelegatingConfigHost.IsAppConfigHttp.get()
    System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.ClientConfigurationSystem()
    System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.EnsureConfigurationSystem()

Inner Exception 1:
ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize

Inner Exception 2:
PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.
```

Comment: PlatformNotSupportedException can have multiple sources & causes. What's the exact & full stack trace?

Comment: Edit includes full exception details with trace

Comment: Probably too obvious to ask, but is .net 7 installed on the machine where the VB is running?

Comment: Yes, all development is being done on the same machine for now

Comment: What version of EF are you using exactly? It doesn't seem to be EF Core?

Comment: As stated, not EF Core. Exact version is EF 6.4.4

Comment: What's important here is the stack that threw PlatformNotSupportedException which is the root cause of issue. It's probably caused by the database (assemblies) you're using as EF 6 itself doesn't throw such error https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/search?q=PlatformNotSupportedException

Comment: Would a C# test program cause the same error? Are you compiling everything for 32bit or AnyCPU?

Comment: Yes, the test console app I reference is specifically compiled as x86 too (although also works when not) and functions correctly. Edit: To clarify here a bit, the library being exposed to COM has to be compiled x86 to be used with COM, the test app works with it regardless of how it's compiled (x86 or Any)